# Deployed SSRS Report displays blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have successfully deployed my first SSRS Report using BIDS, please see image below[image]

I can see the deployed SSRS in the web browser
[image]

But when I click the report name to view/access the report it displays blank and no error!
why is that? I'm new to SSRS R2 , thanks for any help !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My report can be viewed in IE without any problem, but in chrome browser it does not show, so the solution I found is to modify the CSS in the ReportServer

In my case the path is : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles

open the Styleswith notepad and add the ff.

```
div#ctl31_ctl09,
div#ctl31_ctl10
{
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you noticed it, perhaps you didn't, but there's an error message in the deployment output you posted suggesting you have insufficient permissions on the server.

If I were you I would check both "Site Settings" and "Folder Settings" and ensure both have the domain "Francis\Pogrammer" added to the associated security group lists with Content Manager and Publisher permissions.

Comment: yeah, you're right thanks! But I found the ans. by using css . My report can be viewed in IE but for some whatever reason it can't be viewed in chrome.